# Finding the minimum value of $f(x) = \frac{2 \sin (x) + \tan(x) + 3 \cos (x)}{x + \cos (x)}$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2]$

Tags: trigonometry

How can we find the minimum value of this trigonometric function?
$$f(x) = \frac{2 \sin (x) + \tan(x) + 3 \cos (x)}{x + \cos (x)}$$

It is also given that $x \in [0, \pi/2).$

I tried using AM-GM inequality but cannot proceed further. Is there some way to find the minimum value of this function without using differentiation?

Comment: Have you looked at a graph of $f$? It has many vertical asymptotes. Are you sure that the question doesn't restrict the domain over which you want to find a minimum? Of course most of these discontinuities are created by the $\tan$ function which is discontinuous over any interval whose length is bigger than $\pi$.

Comment: @MasB I have edited the question. I forgot to mention the domain of f(x).

Comment: Are you sure that $0$  is not in the interval? If so, then there is no minimum value in the interval as the graph clearly shows. If $0$ is in the interval, then the minimum value is $3$ and $f(0)=3$. Try to show that on the interval $[0,\pi/2)$ the numerator is always at least three times the size of the denominator.

Comment: I tried this using finding slope of 2 sin x + tan x which is always greater than or equal to 3. Is this the only way?

Comment: @ShekharDangi, are you allowed to use the following inequalities ?$$\sin x\geqslant x-\frac{x^3}6\\\tan x\geqslant x+\frac{x^3}3$$ for any $\;x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}2\right[.$

Comment: @Angelo That is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

this problem seems hard to me  so some comment .

We have the inequality on the domain of the OP :

$$2+\frac{1}{3}\frac{2\sin(x)+\tan(x)+3\cos(x)}{\sin\left(x\right)+\frac{\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)^{3}}{6}+\cos\left(x\right)}\leq \frac{2\sin(x)+\tan(x)+3\cos(x)}{x+\cos(x)}$$

You can find a proof of the Taylor series in the denominator via a geometric approach . The last time I see this geometric proof was in a note of a student at *"Polytechnique ecole"* in the 19 th century .

I'm totally unable to show the inequality I mention but perhaps it's the first steps.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the equation to
$3 - \frac{2sin(x)+tan(x)-3x}{x+cos(x)}$. $(2sin(x)+tan(x)-3x)>0$ based on taylor series expansion. Not sure if taylor series is allowed?